# Is there a way to swap columns of a 2d array (matrix) in MiniZinc, and keep track of that?

Tags: arrays, sorting, swap, constraint-programming, minizinc

I'm currently working on MiniZinc.

I got the following 2d array (matrix):

```
0  1  0  0  0  0 
0  1  1  1  0  1 
0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Suppose that it has some order. That the very first column on the left is first, the next one at the right is the second one, and so on, like:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
----------------
0  1  0  0  0  0 
0  1  1  1  0  1 
0  0  0  0  1  1
```

I need a way (like a constraint or something) that helps me to reduce the distance between the very first 1 in a row and the last 1 on that same row. For example, an ideal matrix to that is:

```
1  2  3  4  6  5
----------------
0  1  0  0  0  0 
0  1  1  1  1  0 
0  0  0  0  1  1
```

As you can see, it is by swapping column 5 and column 6 each together. But i don't know how to do this, and keeping track of the order, knowing that the first matrix has [1 2 3 4 5 6] and the second one is [1 2 3 4 6 5]

I really don't know how to model that kind of swapping columns in a 2d variable array.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple way: Say your original data matrix is `data`. You can use an array (say `x`) to keep track of the new order of the columns. To use the new order you use `data[row,x[col]]`, e.g.

```
 [data[row,x[col]] | row in 1..num_rows, col in 1..num_cols]
```

Here is a small example of this. Note that you have to add constraints on `x` to make it more interesting.

```
include "globals.mzn"; 
int: num_rows;
int: num_cols;
array[1..num_rows, 1..num_cols] of int: data;

% decision variables
array[1..num_cols] of var 1..num_cols: x; 

solve satisfy;

constraint
  all_different(x)
  % /\ more constraints on x  ....
;

output [
    "data:\n",
    show2d(data) ++ "\n" ++ 
    "x: \(x)\n",
    "new_data:\n",
    show2d(array2d(1..num_rows, 1..num_cols, [data[i,x[j]] | i in          1..num_rows,j in 1..num_cols])) ++ "\n"
];

% data
num_rows = 3;
num_cols = 6;
data = array2d(1..num_rows,1..num_cols,
  [
  0,1,0,0,0,0,
  0,1,1,1,0,1,
  0,0,0,0,1,1
  ]);
```

One of the solutions is:

```
 data:
 [| 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 |
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1 |
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 |]

 x: [3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6]
 new_data:
 [| 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 |
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 |
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1 |]
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you for your fast response! I didn't have faith on getting this question answered so quickly. But i got another question: since my goal is, like i said before, getting the minimum distance between the first 1 and the last 1 in every row (only by swappping columns, not adding numbers or elements), how can i see that by only manipulating the array x?

Comment: You then have to use the `data[row,x[column]]` structure (instead of  `data[row,column]`) to add constraints to get the minimal distance.

Comment: You can see an example of a similar problem in http://hakank.org/minizinc/tsp_circuit.mzn where `x` "rearranges" a distance matrix and is used together with a circuit constraint (It's a simple TSP model.)